# AucTeX'sTeX-next-error not catching any errors in ConTeXt

Tags: errors, context, auctex

AucTeX's TeX-next-error doesn't display any of the errors listed in the output buffer, only "No more errors".

MWE:

```
\starttext
\Hello
\stoptext

% Local Variables:
% ConTeXt-Mark-version: "IV"
% End:
```

It's my first try with ConTeXt, TeX-next-error has always worked fine for me with LaTeX.

Comment: This question might be better suited for https://emacs.stackexchange.com/ or perhaps even the AucTeX bug tracker.

Comment: You're right. I'm opening it at emacs.stackexchange.com.